# Local SQLite DB in FLex Mobile app

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, mobile

I'm coding an app for Android and iOS devices using Flex. I've an SQLite db already created and I want access to his data. I've seen some code looking with google but I'm not able to run nothing.
I would appreciate if you can explain me where I've to put the file.db into my project and if you share me some simple code that allow to connect to file.db and select some rows. 
Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow will return an object with the data from the database.

```
package bd
{   
    public class SQLPadConnection extends SQLStatement
    {
        protected var _DBFilePatch:String = "DB.sqlite";
        protected var _conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();        

        public function SQLPadConnection() 
        {
            var folder:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath('com.app.directoryName');

            if (!folder.exists) {
                folder.createDirectory();
            }

            _conn.open(folder.resolvePath(_DBFilePatch));       

            this.sqlConnection = _conn;         
            super();
        }

        public function getSQLData(SQL:String = ""):Object
        {           
            if (StringUtil.trim(SQL) != "")
            {               
                this.begin();
                this.text = SQL;
                this.execute();
                this.commit();

                return this.getResult();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
     }
 }
```

To use that, just do like bellow:

```
var res:Object = new Object();
var SQL:SQLPadConnection = new SQLPadConnection();
res = SQL.getSQLData("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
res = SQL.getSQLData("INSERT INTO/ UPDATE/ DELETE...");
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you actually meant AIR, this runtime is what allows you to connect to SQLite. In which case there is gobs of information just in the reference alone...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html